How to create PHAR file on Windows?
I used the following command on OSX:
php -d phar.readonly=0 /usr/bin/phar pack -f $folder/$pluginname.phar $folder/$pluginname

When I try to use similar command on Windows 11 and PHP 8:
php.exe -d phar.readonly=0  C:\PHP\phar.phar.bat pack -f %folder%\%pluginname%.phar %folder%\%pluginname%

I get "%~dp0php.exe" "%~dp0pharcommand.phar" %*.
What is wrong there? How to get phar.phar.bat executed?
